# ASP.NET xsd dataset where do I put it

Tags: asp.net, xsd

I am trying to convert an ASP.NET website into a web application project. The conversion has gone ok I think apart from previously I had 2 xsd files in the App_Code folder. I believe this folder is not used in web applications projects, so where would I put xsd files now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to put them anyplace in particular.  For the purposes of organization you could create a data directory.  If the project is small enough, I leave it in the root.

Comment: Weird I changed my using statements to include the StudentRegistersTableAdapters part and removed it from the code below and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the files wherever you want, but you have to be careful that your namespace references are still correct.

I would look at your Root Namespace declaration in the project properties to ensure that it is set to what you expect it to be.  Also, you will want to look at the location of your TableAdapter objects, as that is where the actual error is, not in the declaration of your StudentQueriesDataTable (Referenced by your xsd as the posted question)